# What is difference between PublishSubject and BehaviorRelay

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

What is the difference between PublishSubject and BehaviorRelay

Comment: How is this not focused? The OP is asking to contrast two specific types in a library. That seems pretty focused to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would make sense to first define the difference between `PublishSubject` and `BehaviorSubject`. Both are observers and subscribers at the same time, meaning they can receive events and be subscribed to. Where they differ is:

**PublishSubject**

1. Starts empty
2. Only emits new values to subscribers

[image]

**BehaviorSubject**

1. Needs a starting value
2. Replays the last value to new subscribers

Once we get this out of the way, the `BehaviorRelay` is easy and the doc says:

> BehaviorRelay is a wrapper for `BehaviorSubject`.
> Unlike `BehaviorSubject` it can't terminate with error or completed.

In other words, Relay won't terminate.

Reference: http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html

[image]